# WeeChat/irc - Tor Proxy

Tags: proxy, irc, tor, weechat

I dont think this is a very hard to solve problem, never the less I didnt find anything about it online. I am pretty new to irc/weechat and obviously dont want to leak my ip whenever i join a room. So I want to use a proxy, specifically tor. The thing is, everything I've tried didnt work out.
For clarity, I now my proxy does work, I tested it on firefox.

---

The things I did to connect an irc server to my proxy where the following:
add tor proxy (no username or password):

```
/proxy add torproxy socks5 <ip-address> 9050
```

set proxy on server:

```
/set irc.server.<server_name>.proxy torproxy
```

then just connect:

```
/connect <server_name>
```

---

and its always the same output:

```
irc: disconnecting from server
irc: reconnecting to server in 10 seconds
```

and after 10 seconds, the exact same output, but with 20 seconds, and the number just goes up

---

some parameters you might want to consider is that I dont run the proxy at localhost. Its a server in my lan, but i tested it on other computers and the proxy does work, so thats not the problem. Also I want to configure the proxy directly in weechat, and not use some system wide setting or something.

---

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to disable SSL verification.

```
/set irc.server.<server_name>.ssl_verify off
```

Another factor to consider is that the server might not accept connections from `tor`. If the network has multiple servers, try connecting to a different one.